# How can i Convert My SQL Query To Linq w/ not equals?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my sql query ;

```
select * from kirala inner join saatler on Kirala.Tarih = '2020-05-31' and Kirala.Onay = 'true' and Kirala.SaatID != saatler.ID
```

i was convert this ;

```
var kirala2 = from t1 in _context.Kirala
                          join t2 in _context.Saatler on t1.SaatID equals t2.ID 
                          where t1.Tarih == "2020-05-31" && t1.Onay == true && t1.YatID == id
                          select new Saatler { Saat = t2.Saat, ID = t2.ID };
```

But this is not working for me because `t1.SaatID equals t2.ID` i cant use not equals what else can I do
 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move all the conditions in the join to a where

```
var kirala2 = from t1 in _context.Kirala
              from t2 in _context.Saatler 
              where t1.SaatID != t2.ID 
                    && t1.Tarih == "2020-05-31" 
                    && t1.Onay == true 
                    && t1.YatID == id
              select new Saatler { Saat = t2.Saat, ID = t2.ID };
```